# Mock inner axios.create()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm using `jest` and `axios-mock-adapter` to test `axios` API calls in `redux` async action creators.

I can't make them work when I'm using a `axios` instance that was created with `axios.create()` as such:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const { REACT_APP_BASE_URL } = process.env;

export const ajax = axios.create({
  baseURL: REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
});
```

which I would consume it in my `async action creator` like:

```
import { ajax } from '../../api/Ajax'

export function reportGet(data) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA })

    try {
      const result = await ajax.post(
         END_POINT_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONS_GET,
         data,
      )
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA, data: result.data })
      return result.data
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my test file:

```
import {
  reportGet,
  REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA,
  RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA,
} from '../redux/TransactionRedux'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { END_POINT_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONS_GET } from 'src/utils/apiHandler'
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const store = mockStore({ transactions: {} })

test('get report data', async () => {
  let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)

  const mockData = {
    totalSalesAmount: 0
  }

  mock.onPost(END_POINT_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONS_GET).reply(200, mockData)

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA },
    { type: RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA, data: mockData },
  ]

  await store.dispatch(reportGet())
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
})
```

And I only get one action `Received: [{"type": "REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA"}]` because there was an error with the `ajax.post`.

I have tried many ways to mock the `axios.create` to no avail without really knowing what I'm doing..Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

OK I got it. Here is how I fixed it! I ended up doing **without** any mocking libraries for `axios`!

Create a mock for `axios` in `src/__mocks__`:

```
// src/__mocks__/axios.ts

const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')

// this is the key to fix the axios.create() undefined error!
mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios)

export default mockAxios
```

Then in your test file, the gist would look like:

```
import mockAxios from 'axios'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

// for some reason i need this to fix reducer keys undefined errors..
jest.mock('../../store/rootStore.ts')

// you need the 'async'!
test('Retrieve transaction data based on a date range', async () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk]
  const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
  const store = mockStore()

  const mockData = {
    'data': 123
  }

  /** 
   *  SETUP
   *  This is where you override the 'post' method of your mocked axios and return
   *  mocked data in an appropriate data structure-- {data: YOUR_DATA} -- which
   *  mirrors the actual API call, in this case, the 'reportGet'
   */
  mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ data: mockData }),
  )

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA },
    { type: RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA, data: mockData },
  ]

  // work
  await store.dispatch(reportGet())

  // assertions / expects
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
  expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Comment: You are my hero :)

Comment: I know this is somewhat older, but you need to return the Promise.resolve ;)

Comment: @ReinierKaper pretty sure the return is implicit in that arrow function pattern :)

Comment: I've been beating my head against the wall trying to solve this problem. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Can you take a look at my particular issue? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745903/mock-custom-instance-of-axios-in-vue-jest-test

Comment: it  is recommended to create \_\_mocks\_\_ directory at the same level whit node_modules, more definition [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)

Comment: This wasn't entirely my solution but it put me on the right path.  I am newbie so maybe I am missing something, but 'src/__mocks__/axios.ts' wasn't auto-loading.  I had to import .. '../__mocks__/..'

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot. I had to add `<typeof axios>` otherwise `mockAxios` was being flagged as `unknown Type`:
`
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule<typeof axios>('axios');
mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios);
`

Comment: if you mock in this way, how you going to test axios header?

Comment: how do you test a negative scenario now by doing Promise.reject({status: 401})? how can you reset module level mock ?

Comment: Might also need to import as `axios` then add `const mockAxios = jest.mocked(axios)` near the top of each test file to stop TypeScript complaining that .mockImplementation... etc doesn't exist

Answer (score 16):

If you need to create **Jest** test which mocks the `axios` with `create` in a specific test (and don't need the mock axios for all test cases, as mentioned in other answers) you could also use:

```
const axios = require("axios");

jest.mock("axios");

beforeAll(() => {
    axios.create.mockReturnThis();
});

test('should fetch users', () => {
    const users = [{name: 'Bob'}];
    const resp = {data: users};
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

    // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
    // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

    return Users.all().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(users));
});
```

Here is the link to the same example of [Axios mocking in Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) without `create`. The difference is to add `axios.create.mockReturnThis()`

Comment: Trying this, I get `TypeError: axios.create.mockReturnThis is not a function`

Comment: Works perfectly as long as you aren't invoking axios.create before the mock can run.  Very nice, thank you.  @mikemaccana I would make sure you are properly mocking axios in that case, shown in the second line

Comment: @mikemaccana if you use with Typescript you need to provide `axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>`

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, which I love because there's no need of adding items in __mocks__ folder or anything else. You, sir, have my upvote.

Comment: I get typescript error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'interceptors')`... `requestInstance.interceptors.request.use(async: (request: any) => { return request; );`

Answer (score 8):

here is my mock for axios

```
export default {
    defaults:{
        headers:{
            common:{
                "Content-Type":"",
                "Authorization":""
            }
        }
  },
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
  post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
  put: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
  delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
  create: jest.fn(function () {
      return {
          interceptors:{
              request : {  
                  use: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
              }
          },

          defaults:{
                headers:{
                    common:{
                        "Content-Type":"",
                        "Authorization":""
                    }
                }
          },
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
          post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
          put: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
          delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
      }
  }),
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In your mockAdapter, you're mocking the wrong instance. You should have mocked ajax instead. like this, `const mock = MockAdapter(ajax)`
This is because you are now not mocking the `axios` instance but rather the `ajax` because it's the one you're using to send the request, ie, you created an axios instance called ajax when you did `export const ajax = axios.create...`so since you're doing `const result = await ajax.post` in your code, its that `ajax` instance of axios that should be mocked, not `axios` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

another method: add this file to `src/__mocks__` folder

```
import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';

const axiosMock = jest.createMockFromModule<AxiosStatic>('axios');
axiosMock.create = jest.fn(() => axiosMock);

export default axiosMock;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution.

```js
import {
  reportGet,
  REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA,
  RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA,
} from '../redux/TransactionRedux'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { END_POINT_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONS_GET } from 'src/utils/apiHandler'
// import axios from 'axios'
import { ajax } from '../../api/Ajax' // axios instance
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const store = mockStore({ transactions: {} })

test('get report data', async () => {
  // let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
  let mock = new MockAdapter(ajax) // this here need to mock axios instance

  const mockData = {
    totalSalesAmount: 0
  }

  mock.onPost(END_POINT_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONS_GET).reply(200, mockData)

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: REQUEST_TRANSACTION_DATA },
    { type: RECEIVE_TRANSACTION_DATA, data: mockData },
  ]

  await store.dispatch(reportGet())
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works!

```
   jest.mock("axios", () => {
        return {
            create: jest.fn(() => axios),
            post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
        };
    });
```

Comment: Only thing need to import `import axios from 'axios'`