# follow jest docs to mock axios but not working

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, axios, jestjs

I flow the jest document to mock module 'axios'

like this

```
// httpCall.js
import axios from 'axios'
export default function httpCall () {
  return axios.get('url/to/the/end/point').then(res => res.data)
}
```

and my test file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import httpCall from './index'
jest.mock('axios')
test('mock module axios', () => {
  const resp = { data: { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' } }
  axios.mockResolvedValue(resp)
  return httpCall().then(res => expect(res).toEqual(resp.data))
})
```

and then got this error

```
TypeError: _axios.default.mockResolvedValue is not a function
```

so I try to google it, then try [Mock inner axios.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393952/mock-inner-axios-create)

create **mocks**/axios-mock.js

```
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')
mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios)
export default mockAxios
```

then update my test file to this

```
import mockAxios from './__mocks__/axios-mock'
import httpCall from './index'
test('mock module axios', () => {
  const resp = { data: { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' } }
  mockAxios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)
  return httpCall().then(res => expect(res).toEqual(resp.data))
})
```

but still got error like below

```
Request failed with status code 404
```

I have no idea about this... but the end I make it working..

this is my mock file

```
// __mocks__/axios-mock.js
import axios from 'axios'
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')
export default axios

// or even like this
import axios from 'axios'
jest.mock('axios')
export default axios
```

this is my test file

```
import httpCall from './index'
import mockAxios from './__mocks__/axios-mock'

describe('mock module', () => {
  it('axios should be mocked', () => {
    const resp = { data: { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' } }
    mockAxios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(resp)
    return httpCall().then(res => expect(res).toEqual(resp.data))
  })
})
```

after it I try move the axios-mock code to test file like this below

```
import axios from 'axios'
import httpCall from './index'
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')

describe('mock module', () => {
  it('axios should be mocked', () => {
    const resp = { data: { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' } }
    mockAxios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(resp)
    return httpCall().then(res => expect(res).toEqual(resp.data))
  })
})
```

I got this error again

```
Request failed with status code 404
```

this is my envinfo

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    jest: ^23.6.0 => 23.6.0
```

my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "modules": "umd"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {

}
```

I hope someone can explain why this is the case

and the [jest mock module document](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) is really working ?

Answer (score 0):

now its working, the issue is my .babelrc file

should like this

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env"
    ]
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "modules": "umd"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/env"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```