# mockup axios with create and post, jestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I am currently realized I shouldn't be calling api straight through network request while using `jestjs` to check for api.

I have been looking at some posts + youtube tutorials such as https://www.leighhalliday.com/mocking-axios-in-jest-testing-async-functions [Mock inner axios.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393952/mock-inner-axios-create/51414152#51414152) but still a bit confused and now sure how to get this to work.

I created a registration api and wanted to do test on it, and after reading the mockup documentation and so on.  I have something like...this as my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

this is how my `base_axios/index.js` looks like, `BASE_URL` is just something like `http://localhost:3000`

```
const axios = require('axios');

const { BASE_URL } = require('../base');

const baseOption = {
    // without adding this, will not be able to get axios response status
    validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status >= 200 && status <= 503;
    },
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
};

module.exports = axios.create(baseOption);
```

### apis/auth.js

```
const request = require('./base_axios');

module.exports = {
    register: data => request.post('/auth/register', data),
};
```

### **mocks**/axios.js

```
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios');

mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios);

module.exports = mockAxios;
```

### routes/auth/register.js

```
const Auth = require('../../apis/auth');
const mockAxios = require('axios');

    test('calls axios for registration', async () => {
        // this should give me an error and show which api has been called
        expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('what is the api');

        const response = await Auth.register();
        console.log(response, 'response'); // response here gives me undefined
    });
```

I am not getting which api call is being called and te response gives me `undefined`
also getting this error from jest `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)`

Thanks in advance for anyone with advice and suggestions.

PS

### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

Comment: Can you please add jest config file, want to check value for roots directory as specified here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#roots-arraystring

Comment: @SanketPhansekar I do have a `jest.config.js` I edited my post

Comment: `const response = await Auth.register();` will of course return undefined since it doesn't return anything. try returning the Promise from `request.post('/auth/register', data)`

Comment: @fubar still nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock axios and an implemtation for it as below:

```
jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockImplementation();
```

For an example:

```
test('calls axios for registration', async () => {
const mockDataRequest = {};
const mockPostSpy = jest
    .spyOn(axios, 'post')
    .mockImplementation(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            return resolve({
                data: {},
            });
        });
    });

expect(mockPostSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

expect(mockPostSpy).toBeCalledWith(
    `/auth/register`,
    expect.objectContaining(mockDataRequest)
);
```

});