# How to mock interceptors when using jest.mock('axios')?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, react-testing-library

When running a test using jest I have the basic test suit syntax:

```
jest.mock('axios');

describe('app', () => {
    let render

    beforeEach(() => {
        axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
            data: {greeting: 'hello there'},
        }),
        render= renderApp()
    });

    test('should render something', () => {
        expect(something).toBeInTheDocument();
    });


});
```

The problem is I have interceptors in my code which when running the test with jest command outputs:

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined*

and points to the interceptors object

`axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(...`

`axiosInstance` is the a variable storing the return of `axios.create`

`export const axiosInstance = axios.create({...`

Refered to this axios thread on SO [How do I test axios in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest) but it doesn't involve any interceptors so didn't really help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was enough in the end, plain and simple `jest.fn()`

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
    return {
        interceptors: {
            request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
            response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: I didb't created axios instance using axios.create, how can I mock interceptors ? 
In my unit test axios is mocked like this 

 jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

Comment: This approach can work for simple stuff but it may lead to needing to mock more and more things manually later. It's often best to use jest's auto-mocking in `__mocks__` like [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414152/568458)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure to mock out the interceptors and `axios.create` if used:

```js
// Replace any instances with the mocked instance (a new mock could be used here instead):
axios.create.mockImplementation((config) => axios);

// Mock out the interceptor (assuming there is only one):
let requestCallback = () => {
  console.log("There were no interceptors");
};
axios.interceptors.request.use.mockImplementation((callback) => {
  requestCallback = callback;
});

// Mock out the get request so that it returns the mocked data but also calls the 
// interceptor code:
axios.get.mockImplementation(() => {
  requestCallback();
  return {
    data: "this is some data"
  };
});
```

**Note** if this doesn't work:

This example assumes that the create and interceptor calls are in a place where Jest can mock them out. Placing the `axios.create` or `axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use` lines outside the scope of the function may cause the above mocking to fail. This is an example file where Jest can mock them out:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const DEBUG = true;

const customRequest = (url) => {
  // Example of axios.create from https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axioscreateconfig
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
  });

  // Example of interceptor taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737325/7470360:
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (DEBUG) { console.info("Request called", config); }
    return config;
  }, (error) => {
    if (DEBUG) { console.error("Request error ", error); }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  return axiosInstance.get(url);
}

module.exports = customRequest;
```

The mocking code will mock out the `axios.create` call and the `axiosInstance` calls in `customRequest`. Moving either the creation or interception outside the function will cause the mocks to fail.

Comment: Tnx for the help however I've been able to mock it with usual jest.mock('axios',callback)
Anyways I've ran into another issue so if you could take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428640/how-to-mock-axios-createconfig-function-to-return-its-instance-methods-inste

Upvoted this answer yesterday

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I mocked `axios.create` and its `interceptors`:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    create: () => {
      return {
        interceptors: {
          request: {eject: jest.fn(), use: jest.fn()},
          response: {eject: jest.fn(), use: jest.fn()},
        },
      };
    },
  };
});
```

Afterwards I was able to call the following in my test code:

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://some-url.com',
});

client.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  // some other test code
  return config;
});
```

Comment: Only example that actually worked for me

Comment: This is useful since when we usually use axios.interceptors it goes with axios.create

Comment: I was creating an axios instance using `axios.create` and mocking it, also had to use interceptors, thank you @Benny!