# mock custom instance of axios in vue jest test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, axios

## The Problem

I have a custom axios instance at `src/axios`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

 const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'myApi/',
 });

export default instance;
```

In `MyComponent` I import `axios` with `import axios from '../axios'` and make an api call.

In testing the api call in `MyComponent` I must mock axios so I do:

`import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');`

but when I run my test `axios` is `undefined` inside `MyComponent` and the test fails.

## What I Tried

1. importing the custom axios instance into the test gives the same error, `axios` is undefined.
2. in `MyComponent` I import `axios` from `node_modules` eg `import axios from 'axios'` then the test works but I can't use my custom `axios` instance.

Vue 2.6, Jest @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest 4.2.3

How can I use the custom instance in `MyComponent` and mock it in the test?

Comment: hey. Been a while since I used Jest but I will try to help. So did you do the `jest.genMockFromModule('axios')` in a `__mocks__` folder? How mock and test come together can be seen here https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/manual-mocks. Just focus on the `__mocks__` and `__tests__` folders. Hope that helps.