# mocking all axios instances with axios-mock-adapter

Tags: node.js, axios, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

Unfortunatelly, attempting to mock the whole axios package in jest test (as below) when `axios.create` is called somewhere doesn't work:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import AxiosMockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
const axiosMock = new AxiosMockAdapter(axios)
```

The only workaround I got so far is to export every axios instance and mock them individually from tests.

I'd want to have axios mocked globally.
I have multiple axios instances created through `axios.create`, and ideally, I would like them to be all mocked through the same AxiosMockAdapter.

I tried playing with jest mock, by setting `global.axiosMock` in jest a `setupFilesAfterEnv` file, but I can't really see this working this way (axios package ends up being undefined anywhere it's called):

```
global.axiosMock = new AxiosMockAdapter(axios)
jest.mock('axios', () => global.axiosMock)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock inner axios.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393952/mock-inner-axios-create)